# redisAI Docker container not setting password

Tags: docker, redis

I am running the latest redisai official image from Docker, but I can't seem to set my password.

I have changed the redis.conf and uncommented `requirepass` followed by my own password.
I then run the image with

```
sudo docker run --name test -v /path/to/redis/conf/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf -p 6379:6379 --gpus all -it --rm redisai/redisai:latest-gpu
```

and when I investigate the configuration

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config get requirepass
1) "requirepass"
2) ""
```

Do I need to set a proper binding?

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config get bind
1) "bind"
2) ""
```

```
127.0.0.1:6379> auth <password>
(error) ERR AUTH <password> called without any password configured for the default user. Are you sure your configuration is correct?
```

I am able to access the server from outside the localhost also.

Answer (score 2):

```
 sudo docker run --name test -v /path/to/redis/conf/redis.conf:/redis.conf -p 6379:6379 --gpus all -it --rm redisai/redisai:latest-gpu redis-server /redis.conf
```

Turns out, I was just missing the last section `redis-server /redis.conf` to initialize the server with the appropriate configuration file.

Comment: You don't need redis-server iirc, just the path to your mounted config file.